# Xlib RGB hex strings: have I understood "scaling in bits"?

Tags: xlib

The xlib docs present two string formats for specifying RGB colours:

> #### RGB Device String Specification
>
> An RGB Device specification is
> identified by the prefix “rgb:” and conforms to the following syntax:
>
> ```
> rgb:<red>/<green>/<blue>
>
>     <red>, <green>, <blue> := h | hh | hhh | hhhh
>     h := single hexadecimal digits (case insignificant)
> ```
>
> Note that `h` indicates the value scaled in 4 bits, `hh` the value scaled in 8 bits,
> `hhh` the value scaled in 12 bits, and `hhhh` the value scaled in 16 bits,
> respectively.
>
> Typical examples are the strings “rgb:ea/75/52” and “rgb:ccc/320/320”,
> but mixed numbers of hexadecimal digit strings (“rgb:ff/a5/0” and
> “rgb:ccc/32/0”) are also allowed.
>
> For backward compatibility, an older syntax for RGB Device is
> supported, but its continued use is not encouraged. The syntax is an
> initial sharp sign character followed by a numeric specification, in
> one of the following formats:
>
> ```
> #RGB          (4 bits each)
> #RRGGBB       (8 bits each)
> #RRRGGGBBB    (12 bits each)
> #RRRRGGGGBBBB (16 bits each)
> ```
>
> The R, G, and B represent single hexadecimal digits. When fewer than 16 bits each are specified, they
> represent the most significant bits of the value (unlike the “rgb:”
> syntax, in which values are scaled). For example, the string “#3a7” is
> the same as “#3000a0007000”.

https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#RGB_Device_String_Specification

So there are strings like either `rgb:c7f1/c7f1/c7f1` or `#c7f1c7f1c7f1`

The part that confuses me is:

> When fewer than 16 bits each are specified, they represent the most significant bits of the value (unlike the “rgb:” syntax, in which values are scaled)

Let's say we have 4-bit colour strings, i.e. one hexadecimal digit per component.

`C` is `12` in decimal, out of `16`.

If we want to scale it up to 8-bits, I guess you have `12 / 16 * 256 = 192`

`192` in hexadecimal is `C0`

So this seems to give exactly the same result as "the most significant bits of the value" i.e. padding with `0` to the right-hand side.

Since the docs make a distinction between the two formats I wondered if I have misunderstood what they mean by "scaling in bits" for the `rgb:` format?

Comment: It is my understanding that in the rgb: format, f is the same as ff, fff and ffff, while in the \# format, f is the same as f0, f00 and f000.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.  I wondered that too, but how do you expand something like `c3`? is it `c333`? or `c300`?

Comment: You scale it this way. The maximum value in 8 bit is ff. The maximum value in 16 bits is ffff. So c3*ffff/ff=c3c3.

Comment: in decimal `ffff` is `65535` and `ff` is `256`. if you do the math then `c3` scaled that way is `49920` in decimal, which is `c300` in hex

Comment: ff is 255, not 256. `0xc3*65536/256` is 0xc300. `0xc3*65535/255` is 0xc3c3.

Comment: ‍♂️  ...thanks, makes sense now